# javascript toggle between tables

Tags: javascript, html, toggle

I have two tables showing different data and on the top of the page there are two buttons.  When you click on one button I want it to show the data for Table A, and when you click on the other button I want it to hide Table A, and show the data in Table B.  The default views for both tables are set to Hide upon page loading and only show when each button is clicked.  What is the javascript functions to make this happen?

Comment: What javascript have you tried to use?

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Comment: Have even tried to use a search engine first? As Brandon points out, there are a lot of similar solutions on the web…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plain JS.

```
<table border="1" id="tableA">
    <tr>
        <td>cell 1</td>
        <td>cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 3</td>
        <td>cell 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table border="1" id="tableB">
    <tr>
        <td>cell 5</td>
        <td>cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell 7</td>
        <td>cell 8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="showTableA" value="Table A">
<input type="button" id="showTableB" value="Table B">
```

```
var tableA = document.getElementById("tableA");
var tableB = document.getElementById("tableB");

var btnTabA = document.getElementById("showTableA");
var btnTabB = document.getElementById("showTableB");

btnTabA.onclick = function () {
    tableA.style.display = "table";
    tableB.style.display = "none";
}
btnTabB.onclick = function () {
    tableA.style.display = "none";
    tableB.style.display = "table";
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/269Zc/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming jQuery:

```
(function($) {

    $(function() {
        var tableA = $('#tableA'),
            tableB = $('#tableB'),
            buttonA = $('#buttonA'),
            buttonB = $('#buttonB');

        buttonA.click(function() {
            tableA.show();
            tableB.hide();
        });

       buttonB.click(function() {
            tableA.hide();
            tableB.show();
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

No offense, but even an extremely cursory search of Google or Stack Overflow would turn up countless examples of how to do this. Chances are your question will be closed, as part of the S.O. code of conduct states that you have to show at least a minimal amount of effort to get things working.